# Javascript, split a string at uppercase and isolate uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to use a regex to split a string at uppercase characters and but also isolates them from the lowercase characters or numbers.

i.e. I'm trying to take a string like this:

`"This is a Test STring"`

and split it into an array like this:

`("T", "his is a ", "T", "est ", "S", "T", "ring")`

I've been trying to tweak a regex similar to the one in this example: 
`match(/[A-Z]?[^A-Z]*)+/g).slice(0,-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could surround the upper-cases with a string of unexpected characters, then split on that string of characters:

```
var s = "This is a Test STring";

var array = s.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '___$1___').split('___');
```

Comment: I like this solution because then you don't have to worry about how to handle non-alphabetic characters elsewhere in your string

Answer (score 3):

You could use this regex:

```
([A-Z]|[a-z ]+)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/lH6hB0

Javascript:

```
var str = "This is a Test STring"; 
var res = str.match(/([A-Z]|[a-z ]+)/g);
```

The result of `res` will be an array with the values:

```
"T", "his is a", "T", "est", "S", "T", "ring"
```

Comment: tweaked it a little to address for numbers

`([A-Z]|[a-z0-9 ]+)`

Comment: For *anything* that's not a cap: `\W|[a-z0-9_ ]`, so to complete this: `/[A-Z]|\W|[a-z0-9_ ]+/g` -- http://jsfiddle.net/mhfaust/Z88XN/